# SSIS open package being executed by execute package task

Tags: ssis, package, execute

So i have uses SSIS a while, and have many jobs with execute package task in them.

Is there a short cut to open the package that is actually being executed in this task.

I cant see any options in the right click menu, or other menus etc.?

thanks

Comment: You deploy ISPAC file of your solution, but to open your packages you need .sln (solution) files. If you don't have solution file you can reverse engineer the ISPAC file to get solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no shortcut.  You have to note the name of the package, and open it normally in BIDS.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16606125)

Comment: Uh, of course it answers the question.   The question was "Is there a short cut.."

Comment: Thanks for your response. I marked this because I feel like the content from your post could be a comment. There are many discussions about what kind of response should be a comment or an answer, and there are no clear cuts. So I could be wrong about marking your post. We can wait and see what other reviewers think about this.

Comment: im happy with tab alleman answer, if there indeed is no shortcut, that is the answer